# View to display nodes with a random term

Tags: views

I have got a view that selects some images. Each image is tagged with a taxonomy term. I would like the view to display only images tagged with a common term that is chosen randomly at every use.

The view is used as a block.

Example:
term: a, images: img1, img2, img3;
term: b, images: img4;
term: c, images: img5, img6;

One user sees a sequence of img1, img2 and img3. Another one sees img4 only. A next one sees img4 too.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up an argument (D6) / contextual filter (D7) to filter the view results based upon a taxonomy term, and then for the argument/filter value, select the PHP option for providing the default, and in there randomly return one of your taxonomy terms.  Without actually testing the code, I would imagine using [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) would make this rather trivial, eg:

```
$terms=array('foo','bar','baz');
return $terms[array_rand($terms)];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I added a condition to select only used terms. My final code is:
`
    $tids = array();  
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree(4);  
    foreach ($terms as $term) {  
     $tids[] = $term->tid;  
    }  
    $result = db_query('SELECT DISTINCT tid FROM taxonomy_index WHERE tid IN (:tids)', array(':tids' => $tids));  
    $tids = $result->fetchCol();  
    return $tids[array_rand($tids)];  
`